# search by multiple field. sometimes by one field and sometimes more than one field

Tags: php, mysql

I have search form. in here multiple field. sometimes I will form submit with one field, sometimes form submit with two and sometimes multiple field value.

```
     if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $projectName     = $_POST['pName'];
        $clientId      = $_POST['s_by_clientName'];
        $departmentId  = $_POST['s_by_department'];
        $statusName  = $_POST['s_by_status'];
        if (!empty($projectName)) 
        {
            $searchSql = mysql_query("select * from project_list where projectName='$projectName'");
        }

        if (!empty($clientId)) 
        {
            $searchSql = mysql_query("select * from project_list where client_id='$clientId'");
        }

        if (!empty($departmentId)) 
        {
            $searchSql = mysql_query("select * from project_list where department_id='$departmentId'");
        }

        if (!empty($statusName)) 
        {
            $searchSql = mysql_query("select * from project_list where status='$statusName'");
        }

    }
```

these query only for search by single field.
     how to make query that performs searching by one or multiple field value
     is it possible??

Comment: mysql_query() has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Kindly update your code to use mysqli library of PDO. Try storing the search params in an array and append using AND or OR in your query if more than one field submitted.

Comment: oh yes... it's a existing project. just simply customizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Concatenation in query Variable

```
 $searchSql ="select * from project_list where 1=1 ";
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $projectName     = $_POST['pName'];
    $clientId      = $_POST['s_by_clientName'];
    $departmentId  = $_POST['s_by_department'];
    $statusName  = $_POST['s_by_status'];
    if (!empty($projectName)) 
    {
        $searchSql. = " AND projectName='$projectName'";
    }
    if (!empty($clientId)) 
    {
        $searchSql. = " AND client_id='$clientId'";
    }
    if (!empty($departmentId)) 
    {
        $searchSql. = " AND department_id='$departmentId'";
    }
    if (!empty($statusName)) 
    {
        $searchSql. = " AND status='$statusName'";
    }
}
$result=mysql_query($searchSql);
```

NOTE:mysql_query() has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Kindly update to use mysqli library of PDO.

Comment: Thank you so mutch...@Sanooj T

Comment: ")" no need closing parenthesis at the end of query

Comment: Awesome example of what not to do; using user input in a query without properly escaping the values is a big nono

Comment: Ok i just answer his question but as you said i must warn him thanks@Ja͢ck

Answer (score 1):

You can build an increntale query

```
<code>
 if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $projectName     = $_POST['pName'];
    $clientId      = $_POST['s_by_clientName'];
    $departmentId  = $_POST['s_by_department'];
    $statusName  = $_POST['s_by_status'];
    $my_sql = "select * from project_list "; 
    $my_where = "";
    if (!empty($projectName)) 
    {
        if ($my_where = ""){
            $my_sql .= "where ";
        } else {
            $my_sql .= "and ";
        }
        $my_sql .= "projectName='$projectName'";

    }
    if (!empty($clientId)) 
    {

        if ($my_where = ""){
            $my_sql .= "where ";
        } else {
            $my_sql .= "and ";
        }
        $my_sql .=  "client_id='$clientId'";

    }
    if (!empty($departmentId)) 
    {
        if ($my_where = ""){
            $my_sql .= "where ";
        } else {
            $my_sql .= "and ";
        }
        $my_sql .=  "department_id='$departmentId'";


    }
    if (!empty($statusName)) 
    {
        if ($my_where = ""){
            $my_sql .= "where ";
        } else {
            $my_sql .= "and ";
        }
        $my_sql .=  "status='$statusName'";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I used column `id` as `primary key` & `auto-increment`. Change it as per your column name.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM project_list WHERE id is not null";
```

**Code**

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $projectName     = $_POST['pName'];
    $clientId      = $_POST['s_by_clientName'];
    $departmentId  = $_POST['s_by_department'];
    $statusName  = $_POST['s_by_status'];

    // Here I used coloumn 'id' as primary key & auto-increment. Change it as per your column name.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM project_list WHERE id is not null"

    if (!empty($projectName)) 
    {
        $query. = " AND projectName='".$projectName."'";
    }
    if (!empty($clientId)) 
    {
        $query. = " AND client_id='".$clientId."'";
    }
    if (!empty($departmentId)) 
    {
        $query. = " AND department_id='".$departmentId."'";
    }
    if (!empty($statusName)) 
    {
        $query. = " AND project_list='".$statusName."'";
    }

     $searchSql = mysql_query($query);
}
```